# How to Open New Screen in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I am following this article to learn how to open new screen on button click:
http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html

**But I am getting 3 error messages like this:**

```
      Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
R cannot be resolved to a variable  screen1.java    /screen1/src/test/android   line 20 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  screen1.java    /screen1/src/test/android   line 21 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  screen2.java    /screen1/src/test/android   line 13 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  screen2.java    /screen1/src/test/android   line 14 Java Problem
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output.   screen1     line 1  Android ADT Problem
```

**This is what I have done till now:**

**screen1.java**

```
    package test.android;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;




public class screen1 extends Activity
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
      Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClick);
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Intent i = new Intent(screen1.this, screen2.class);
         startActivity(i);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**screen2.java**

```
    package test.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class screen2 extends Activity
{
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
   {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
      Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick2);
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         setResult(RESULT_OK);
         finish();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="test.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
     <activity android:name=".Screen1" android:label="Screen 1">
        <activity android:name=".screen1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Screen2"  android:label="Screen 2">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**screen1.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="You are in the first Screen"
/>
<Button
   android:id ="@+id/btnClick"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Open New Screen"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**screen2.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="You are in the New Screen"
/>
<Button
   android:id ="@+id/btnClick2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Close"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

To give you an idea, this is screenshot of my project

http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/8883/projscreen.jpg

**Please help guys !**

Comment: Try clean and rebuild your project, it should be automatically generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting your button ids as `id ="@+id/btnClick"` , use `android:id ="@+id/btnClick"`
It is always a good idea to read the comments of the tutorials that you follow if you have problems, this fix was just 3-4 comments down.

Also if you look at the line numbers referenced: 18 in screen1.java and 13 in screen2.java, you'll find that the problem happens when you reference your button ids.

Comment: hi, I just made those changes and now getting 5 errors. Please see my code above (I just updated my code in the above post).

Comment: Do what @MByD suggests, right-click your project, select 'clean selected projects' and try to run again.

Comment: I am using Eclipse and yes I did clean after removing import android.R but still getting 5 errors that I posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my first answer was nonsense. But I've noticed that you're declaring a screen1 activity inside a screen1 activity in your manifest. You only need 1, with the label "@string/app_name" and with the intent filter.

Try changing that, clean the project and let me know if anything changes.

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference mate, its taking the id's from R.layout not from R.id. R.layout should be automatically generated based on the file names in res/layout

Comment: Ah. True story. I've always enjoyed the good practice of giving everything an appropriate id myself. But I suppose it doesn't break anything.

Comment: hi, I just updated my code in the above post. Please see the screenshot of my project and let me know if I have all files on the right place/location.

Answer (score -1):

What is your import android.R doing?
I think your R.java is not generated? is it?

Coz i just worked on it on my eclipse i didnt find import android.R? and it worked completely fine.

Comment: Just get rid of that android.R thing from ure import and try clean and build your project if you are using eclipse.

Comment: I did remove import android.R but still getting 5 errors which I updated above, please see and help me

Comment: what's your IDE? eclipse or Netbeans or somthing else? is your R.java file generated?

Comment: I am using eclipse and developing for 2.2 froyo. If you see the screenshot I posted above, I just realized that I was having 2 manifest files (by mistake I created a new in res/layout. Now I just deleted that and update the default manifest and now I am not getting any error. BUT  the strange thing is that I am not getting any OUTPUT. I just updated my manifest in the code above. Please help. I even tried installing the app on my phone but I don't see app in menu or anywhere and no output in virtual emulator.

Comment: I suggest you creating a new project and not playing up with the manifest file

Comment: But the tutorial that I am following (posted above), manifest code is mentioned. So that code will be created automatically ?

Comment: you need not create a manifest file on your own ure ide does it for you. So why mess with manifest file.

Comment: Hello Rovin, I just created a new project and tried to run the project. It was working fine but I realized that screen 2 was throwing error so I added the BOLD code mentioned in the tutorial (activity for screen 2) in manifest and now everything is working fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad i was awake till midnight wandering what you did with manifest file. Glad i helped you, now i wanna sleep